# Errors shown in terminal when editing files with gedit

Tags: command-line, gedit

When editing any file f.e. like this:

```
r@ngf:~$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
[sudo] password for r: 

(gedit:1638): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Не удалось создать файл «/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.CJP8XV»: Нет такого файла или каталога

(gedit:1638): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Нет такого файла или каталога

(gedit:1638): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Не удалось создать файл «/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.W8MHYV»: Нет такого файла или каталога

(gedit:1638): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Нет такого файла или каталога

(gedit:1638): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Не удалось создать файл «/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.DZG7XV»: Нет такого файла или каталога

(gedit:1638): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/root/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

It is shows some errors, but this doesn't affect on the editing actually -- files     saves normally. So what that errors could mean?

Answer (score 7):

First, you shouldn't use `sudo` with GUI programs. Use `gksudo` instead.

As for the warnings: they are harmless. They just say that gedit tries to save a file at a location that does not exist. If you want to make them go away, you got to create that location:

```
sudo mkdir -p /root/.local/share
```

Comment: Hmm... interesting, that's the first time I hear that with gui programs I have to use gksudo.

Comment: You don't have to, but it's strongly recommended. Using `sudo`, the `$HOME` variable will stay `/home/your_user`, probably causing files written to your home directory as root user - something you don't want. Using `gksudo` on the other hand, the `$HOME` variable will be set to `/root`.

Comment: sometimes the sudo command is more useful for a GUI application, especially with regards to troubleshooting, or if you need your own directory to be set as $HOME. Using either doesn't do much harm, gksudo is just considered the proper way to do things in GUI